# Challenging scenario for designing database with RBAC approach

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship, rbac

I am trying to design an ER model for my database using RBAC approach.

This is the description:
The company has many **employees**, each employee has several **functional roles** and an **organizational role**. Functional role consists of three roles counselor, counselee and super user. 
Each **group** consists of a counselor and N counselees, all groups are under supervision of a super user.
The counselor of the group can only edit the reports of his/her counselees.

My question is should I create separate tables for both functional roles and organizational roles? or is there any better approach for this scenario?

The challenging part is about the part which a user can be a counselor in group A and be a counselee in group B at the same time.

Comment: you'll need PERSON, ORGANIZATION, and GROUP tables, and then linker tables in between with a column for the 'role' and possibly the dates where this relationship was active.

Comment: So for instance we put Functional Role in a separate table as you said, but what about Organizational Role? Should it be as an attribute in PERSON table? and then how we can handle the challenging part as I mentioned in my question

Comment: there would be one relationship table between People and Groups and another table between people and Organization - each would have its own Role attribute

Comment: Have you looked into existing solutions? RBAC or ABAC frameworks?

Comment: I tried to manage it with ABAC framework, but it was quite complex, I found a similar solution here 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/user-rolesgroupspermissions
But still it has some doubts, I start trying in practical and find out what kind of problems I will face

Comment: Sounds like some of your many:many tables need to have 3 ids, not just 2.